# find_if find a element not equal to something

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, iterator

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int  matrix[9] = { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,5 };
    bool status = true;

    status = find_if(begin(matrix), end(matrix), [](auto const &value) ->bool
    { if (value != 0 && value != 1) return false; else return true; });

        cout << status << endl;

}
```

I have a situation where I need to find if there is a value which is not equal to `1` and `0` present in the array. I thought of using `find_if`. But I am not able to make it work.

This code always `return true`. How do I make it right? The final status should be `false` if atleast one of the element in the array is non `1 and 0`.

Is the `find_if` method the correct one here?

Comment: find_if returns iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_if` returns an iterator. In the case of the integer array it returns a pointer of type `int *` that is always converted to `true` because it is not a  null pointer.

you should write instead

```
status = find_if(begin(matrix), end(matrix), [](auto const &value) ->bool
{ if (value != 0 && value != 1) return false; else return true; }) != end( matrix );
```

Another way is to use the standard algorithm `std::any_of` that indeed returns a Boolean value.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns an iterator, not a `bool`. In your case the iterator is a pointer, which should never be null, and thus will always implicitly convert to `true`.

You're looking for [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

Comment: Or just compare the result to .end()